# Generic Sort for Number or Alphabet in Ascending or Descending Order

Tags: c#, arrays, algorithm, sorting

**How can I sort Generic array which can contain alphabet or numbers only?**

> Lets say I have a generic list of array that contains numbers only and
>   can be easily sort using

```
 public void sortAsc(ref T[] obj)

   {
      do
            {
                didSwap = false;
                for (int i = 0; i < obj.Length - 1; i++)
                {
                    if (Convert.ToInt32(obj[i]) < Convert.ToInt32(obj[i + 1]))
                    {
                        T temp = obj[i + 1];
                        obj[i + 1] = obj[i];
                        obj[i] = temp;
                        didSwap = true;
                    }
                }
            } while (didSwap);

   }
```

but if array contains string of names and we wants to sort in same way will fail.

due to this

> if (Convert.ToInt32(obj[i]) < Convert.ToInt32(obj[i + 1]))

Please let me know if there is a generic method for this or I will have to separate logic for each.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at the [`List<T>.Sort()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.sort?view=netframework-4.7.2) method as this will do what you need.

It solves your problem of having to use `Convert.ToInt32` because by default it will use the `IComparer` implementation of the actual class being used, which both `int` and `string` have already for you.

So for strings:

```cs
var list = new List<string> { "dd", "aa", "ss" };
list.Sort();

//Output: list = ["aa", "dd", "ss"]
```

Or for integers:

```cs
var list = new List<int> { 1, 13, 5 };

list.Sort();

//Output: list = [1, 5, 13]
```

If you want to work with custom classes, just make your class implement `IComparable` or by having the caller to `Sort()` to provide a function delegate to use. See the first link for more details in the docs.